# How to debug Python application using another project instead of PIP package?

Tags: python, pycharm

So, I have a Python project that depends on another.  Normally, I pull that package from a repo using pip.  However, I want to make local changes to it and test both my primary project and that package together (in PyCharm, specifically).

How do I do that?  Do I have to pip install the package first?  How do I then get my project to reference the local copy of the the package's source code?